# running your programe on a cluster in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, parallel-processing, fortran, cluster-computing, hpc

I have a programming program written in fortran installed. It makes use of packages such as Lapack (Linear algebra package) that have to have root privileges to install. I have access to a cluster in my university which does not have the required packages installed. Can I compile this program on my computer but run the executable .o file in the cluster?

I also have other computers connected to the network. Can you point me to a source/tutorial so that I can use those other computers to shorten my program execution time. If I ask my friends to leave their computers on when they are away, how do I use them?

Comment: interesting question. trying to build another BOINC ?

Comment: Just looked at BOINC. It seems like a great idea. But no, I am just trying to do some parallel programming without having to ask the computer maintainers to install additional things for me

Comment: you can read more about parallel clustering of Ubuntu at : http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud

Comment: Most clusters in universities have a set of reserved nodes for compiling so that you compile your program in the environment where it will run. Matt suggested in his answer that you compile libraries in your hone directory on the cluster. In most cases you don't need to compile your own version unless you need some old or very recent version of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To build/install (scientific) software easily without having root priveleges, see EasyBuild (http://hpcugent.github.com/easybuild).

Answer (score 0):

There are several variables in this question, but theoretically yes, you should be able to compile on one system for use on another, but making sure that all of the versions matchup and are compatible across systems can be very complicated and time consuming.

A simpler solution might be to compile the libraries you need in your home directory on the cluster you have access to.  Generally most clusters at academic institutions should have a pretty good variety of compilers and libraries available.

Making use of friend's computers that are left on overnight for computation is also theoretically possible but would largely depend on the code being run, capabilities of compute nodes, network environment and system resource requirements.